# Default value for complex type in action method

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have an action method in Controller with some class as parameter. How to setup default values for properties in that class for specific action method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you could use a custom model binder? So your action method would look like:

```
public ActionResult Test([ModelBinder(typeof(ACustomModelBinder))] Models.TestC id)
```

The model binder would look something like:

```
public class ACustomModelBinder : DefaultModelBinder
{
    public override object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        // Bind anything that can be bound by default
        Models.TestC model = (Models.TestC)base.BindModel(controllerContext, bindingContext);

        // Set any other properties from the request (in your case, none)
        // model.SomeProeprty = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue("AProperty").AttemptedValue;

        // Set the defaults that you want
        model.Name = "default name";
        model.Age = "27";

        return viewModel;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the "elegant" way.  You can simple create an object, set its default values and then pass it to the controller. I do this to setg the date as Today() as default value... without creating a custom binder.

Comment: I wanted to avoid creating custom binder. Unfortunatelly I created because of no other option. I created also custom attribute instead using ModelBinder directly.

Answer (score 0):

Route should like this.
 routes.MapRoute(
                  "Default1", // Route name
                    "{controller}/Test/{id}", // URL with parameters
                    new { controller = "Home", action = "Test", id = new MvcApplication19.Models.TestC() { Name = "Test11111" } }
                    );

```
   // Model
   public class TestC
   {
    public string Name { get; set; }
   }
   // Action method in controller
   public ActionResult Test(Models.TestC id)
    {
        return Content(id.Name);
    }
```

This can help you. If not provide some more information.

Comment: Nice, but if I use that then "id" is not bind from request